# Create SimpleXMLElement Node with Namespace and prevent namespace repeating

Tags: php, xml, symfony, namespaces, simplexml

For a google sitemap I want to create XML nodes with namespace. How can I prevent simplexml from inserting the namespace on each node.

Structure that I need:

```
<xhtml:link 
             rel="alternate"
             hreflang="de"
             href="http://www.example.com/deutsch/"
             />
```

Structure from my code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
       <url>
          <loc>www.url.ch</loc>
          <xhtml:link xmlns:xhtml="xhtml" rel="alternate" hreflang="de-CH" href="www.url.ch/de">www.url.ch/de</xhtml:link>
          <xhtml:link xmlns:xhtml="xhtml" rel="alternate" hreflang="fr-CH" href="www.url.ch/fr">www.url.ch/fr</xhtml:link>
       </url>
    </urlset>
```

My Code:

```
        $rootNode = new SimpleXMLElement(
            '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' .
            '   <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></urlset>'
        );

        $urlNode = $rootNode->addChild('url');
        $urlNode->addChild('loc', 'www.url.ch');

        foreach (['de', 'fr', 'it', 'en'] as $locale) {
            if (in_array($locale, ['it', 'en'])) {
                continue;
            }

            $localeNode = $urlNode->addChild(
                'xhtml:link',
                'www.url.ch' . '/' . $locale,
                'xhtml'
            );

            $localeNode->addAttribute('rel', 'alternate');
            $localeNode->addAttribute('hreflang', $locale . '-CH');
            $localeNode->addAttribute('href', 'www.url.ch' . '/' . $locale);
        }

        $rootNode->saveXML($filePath);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the namespace in the `addChild` call as the globally unique "namespace identifier" (URI) not the "local prefix". So in this case, you are binding the `xhtml` prefix as `xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` so the namespace URI is `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`:

```
$localeNode = $urlNode->addChild(
    'xhtml:link',
    'www.url.ch' . '/' . $locale,
    'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'
);
```

The XML library then looks up the already-assigned prefix for this namespace when generating the XML, and gives the desired result.

Comment: Thanks IMSoP. That was it.